# How to continue a script after AJAX response is sent to user in Yii2?

Tags: ajax, yii2, response

After receiving an AJAX request, I want to give feedback to the user before the PHP script finishes, because it takes long.

I thought that the [`send()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#send()-detail) method of the `yii\web\Response` object was made for that, so I tried the following inside the controller action:

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
Yii::$app->response->data = [ 'success' => $someData ];
Yii::$app->response->send();

// code that takes long
sleep(5);
```

The response is sent, but after sleeping for 5 seconds.

Same luck with:

```
ob_start();
echo json_encode([ 'success' => $someData ]);
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
flush();

// code that takes long
sleep(5);
```

I didn't have any confidence in this last code working inside a controller action, but I had it in the first one... what am I missing?

**EDIT**: I'm using nginx + PHP_FPM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP_FPM has [`fastcgi-finish-request()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) available:

> This function flushes all response data to the client and finishes the
>   request. This allows for time consuming tasks to be performed without
>   leaving the connection to the client open.

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
Yii::$app->response->data = [ 'success' => $someData ];
Yii::$app->response->send();

fastcgi-finish-request();

// code that takes long
sleep(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you searching for is the **long polling**

Here is fine working example for long polling implementation on PHP+jQuery

https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling

And here is related topic with deep explanation of different technologies in that area (including long polling) -- [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

Also you can take a look at this video tutorial

https://www.screenr.com/SNH

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not quite sure that's what I'm looking for. I need some time to dig into the topic, but I surely will come back.

Comment: I'm here in 2021 to say that this "long polling" git link is literally just a loop of AJAX... It just requests data again and again. And the PHP script is just set up in a way that it only "ends" and outputs a response when something has changed... This is definitely NOT doing anything similar to a websocket or push notification.